# Using controller for image download results in slow load and error in console

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.4, download

I have a custom controller which is outputting file information (image/png) that has been uploaded to the server. Short version looks like this:

```
class MyController extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    public function execute(){
        // $fullpath becomes abs path on server to my png
        $info = [];
        $info['quote_path'] = $fullpath; 
        $info['order_path'] = $fullpath;
        $info['title']      = "quote item";
        // @var $this->download \Magento\Sales\Model\Download
        $this->download->downloadFile($info);
    }
}
```

This works fine on my local server, but on my remote server the file doesn't download. Nor does it display properly on my page. I am using the controller path as my `img`'s `src` attribute and I get an error in chrome:

```
net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
```

The image appears to load, albeit excruciatingly slow, but then it fails.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Not sure if this is related but the `Expires` header returned with the image is a year in the past.

The file is 15.8KB

Answer (score 0):

Another obscure issue brought about by a simple problem.

I used the class `Magento\Sales\Controller\Download\DownloadCustomOption` as a model and noticed something missing in my own class. The fix so far seems to be the need for this function before the end of my `execute()` function, since I'm not returning a result page in my controller. Here it is:

```
execute(){
    ...
    $this->endExecute();
}
```

So far seems to be working, not positive this was my only problem yet.